# Android Emulator Device crash when start in Android Studio (Linux)

Tags: android, linux, genymotion

When I start that device it was crashed and show this error in the console of Android Studio:

> emulator64-arm:
>   ../../../../../../../src/mesa/drivers/dri/i915/i915_fragprog.c:1225:
>   i915BindProgram: Assertion `p->on_hardware == 0' failed.

When I use `Genymotion` it is disposed without any error notice.

Comment: Maybe you need to Uncheck the "Use Host GPU" checkbox - in the emulator settings

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it work perfectly :)

Comment: I will write an answer for the others that will encounter the same problem. can you check it?

Comment: I did it. Sorry for late :D

Comment: stop docker if it's running. https://www.bram.us/2017/05/12/fix-for-the-android-emulator-crashing-during-launch/ worked well with Mac OS  10.12.5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to Uncheck the "Use Host GPU" checkbox - in the emulator settings

Comment: Excuse me, could you tell me why if we choose that option, the emulator will crash? If I want to use this option, how can I fix it?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know. This option works perfect on my computer. Try changing computer or different emulator.

Comment: For me, it was working but then suddenly it stopped.

Comment: This checkbox doesn't exist (anymore).

Answer (score 17):

For emulator crashing seconds after launch in Android Studio 2.3.1 or later: Open Android Virtual Device Manager, select your AVD, select "Edit this AVD", in the new window (Virtual Device Configuration),  goto Emulated Performance > Graphics and select the "Software (GLS)" option. This problem might be caused by:
1) Outdated graphics card drivers.
2) Older graphics cards, not properly supported by the generic Windows 8 (or newer) drivers.

Comment: I can't select anything. Graphics is "Automatic" and can't be changed. Only thing that helps for a while is reboot the PC. It's annoying. If it would at least say what caused the crash... Crap. "This problem might be caused by " AVD developers who don't know what they are doing.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when I used my PC in combination with an USB docking station (DisplayLink). In this case you have to ensure to use the software emulation. Without the DisplayLink connection it works with GPU support as expected.

Comment: I also have this problem when using a USB -> DVI adapter. So as its not using the native GFX drivers and using the drivers/hardware of the adapter, it isn't powerful enough t o run the emulator with hardware backed OpenGS

Answer (score 1):

For simply, a cold start was the solution.

1. Open AVD-Manager
2. Select "Cold Boot now"

Answer (score 0):

In versions prior to Android Studio 4.0, I have had to either:

- Run `optirun android-studio` so my Optimus GPU is enabled and hardware rendering can be used.
- Force the emulator to use "Software Rendering" (Automatic doesn't work).

Neither of these choices work for me with Android Studio 4.0, however I have found that I can go into "Advanced Settings" and switch the emulator to "Cold Boot", and then it will once again work, including with hardware rendering if I use `optirun` to start Android Studio.